# LEGO EV3 on Chromebooks not recognizing NXT bricks

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, nxt

I teach two LEGO robotics classes in middle school and in one of my classes I am using EV3 and in the other NXT.  I was able to have these classes because of the Chromebook app, but the problem I am having is the EV3 Chromebook app is not recognizing the NXT's.  Everywhere I read said they were compatible.  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Do you have references/links for "everywhere I read". I have not seen anything that says NXT is compatible with the chromebook software.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the EV3 programing on our PC's before it was released on chromebooks.  It was my assumption that the EV3 Chromebook app would also be compatible.

Answer (score 1):

NXTs require a special USB driver, which is only available for Windows and Mac, so programming NXTs with official LEGO software will only work with those platforms. (EV3's use a generic USB HID driver.)

Furthermore, using NXTs via Bluetooth is not supported in any of the official LEGO EV3 software products.